# How to convert integer to decimal place ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I have a whole number `91125`, and should make of it a decimal `911,25`. How can I convert it using classic ASP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide the number for 100

```
number = 91125
new_number = formatNumber((number/100),2)
```